# Get different tag classes preserving their order using selenium C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I'm scraping an ePUB bible (which has HTML pages for each chapter) and I want to preserve the order of a few tags that are spread over the HTML page.
All bible chapters are similar and written like this or a variation of this:

```
<div>
  <p class="p">
  <a class="v">1</a> This is a verse.
  <a class="v">2</a> This is a verse. 
  <a class="v">3</a> This is a verse.
  </p>
  <h3 class="s1">This is a pericope</h3>
  <h4 class="r">This is a reference for this pericope.</h4>
  <p class="p">
  <a class="v">4</a> This is a verse.
  <a class="v">5</a> This is a verse. 
  </p>
  <p class="p">
  <a class="v">6</a> This is a verse with a quote:
  </p>
  <p class="q">"This is the content</p>
  <p class="q">of a quote;</p>
  <p class="q">or a spoken word."</p>
  <h3 class="s1">This is another pericope</h3>
  ...
</div>
```

Essentially:

```
<class="v"> is a "a" element with the number of the verse
<class="p"> is a "p" element with a verse or a collection of verses;
<class="q"> is a blockquote;
<class="s1"> is a pericope;    
<class="r"> is a reference to a periscope;
```

Getting all p elements can give me quite good results, that was linked to another related question on SO, but is it possible to scrap a page preserving the order of the calls?

For the example above, I would be able to get the elements in order following their classes, so I can re-write in text the content of that chapter as:

> 1 This is a verse.
> 2 This is a verse.
> 3 This is a verse.
> **This is a pericope.**
> *This is a reference for this pericope.*
> 4 This is a verse.
> 5 This is a verse.
> 6 This is a verse with a quote:
> "This is the content
> of a quote;
> or spoken word"
> **This is another periscope**
>
> ...

Can't seem to find a way using Selenium, but if there's what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code block and update me the status :

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.xpath("//*[(self::p) or (self::p and following-sibling::a) or (self::h3) or (self::h4)]"));
foreach (IWebElement element in elements) 
{
    string my_text = element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
    Console.WriteLine(my_text);
}
```

The Output on my console is as :

```
1 This is a verse.
2 This is a verse. 
3 This is a verse.
This is a pericope
This is a reference for this pericope.
4 This is a verse.
5 This is a verse.
6 This is a verse with a quote:
"This is the content
of a quote;
or a spoken word."
This is another pericope
```

### Update :

See the `xpath` is correct and returning me correct results. Here is the snapshot :

[image: Bible]

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB. Tried this code block, but the first line didn't grab any element at all. Not sure what to do here, but looks like the XPath string doesn't do it's job. I'm using VS 2015 , Selenium version 3.6.0 from Nuget, if that matters.

Comment: Yeah. The XPath string IS working indeed on online testers but I cant replicate it on VS. I will see if I can find whats wrong with it. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Great !!! May be you need to fix up the `VS`. Please Accept the Answer by clicking on the tick mark beside my Answer which is just below the VoteDown arrow so the arrow turns green.